# My spark join runs out of memory unexpectedly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory

I have some code which compares objects to see if they're duplicates or near-duplicates of each other.  To support this I'm doing a big join in spark.  Keys might occur thousands of times (but never more than 12K times) on each side of the join.  For each joined pair I do some work; if a duplicate pair is detected I emit a record, and otherwise I emit nothing.

```
val leftSide: RDD[(String, FeaturesRecord)] = ...
val rightSide: RDD[(String, FeaturesRecord)] = ...
val result = leftSide.join(rightSide).values().flatMap({
  case (featuresRecord1, featuresRecord2) => {
    val score = computeSimilarity(featuresRecord1, featuresRecord2)
    if (score > 0.9) {
      Some(OutputRecord(featuresRecord1.id, featuresRecord2.id, score))
    } else {
      None
    }
  })
```

This runs very slowly and often runs out of memory.

I could probably fix the problem by just using an extremely large number of partitions.
But instead I'd like to understand why this is causing a problem.  In theory, spark should be able to keep most of this data on disk.  It could do something like this:

- load all FeaturesRecords associated with a given String key into memory (max 24K FeaturesRecords)
- compare them pairwise and have a Seq containing the outputs
- every time the Seq has more than 10K elements, flush it out to disk
- abandon and garbage-collect the FeaturesRecords before moving on to the next String key

so in theory this should never require more memory than 24K * sizeof(FeaturesRecord) + 10K * sizeof(OutputRecord).

The join code says:

```
  def join[W](other: RDD[(K, W)], partitioner: Partitioner): RDD[(K, (V, W))] = self.withScope {
    this.cogroup(other, partitioner).flatMapValues( pair =>
      for (v <- pair._1.iterator; w <- pair._2.iterator) yield (v, w)
    )
  }
```

which certainly looks like it's doing that, but honestly those iterators could be doing anything and it's hard to tell.

Why is this running out of memory?

(I'm using spark-2.4, and unfortunately I don't have the ability to upgrade.)

Comment: instead of join to compare row, why dont use except and look at result ?

Comment: I'm looking for FeatureRecords that are near-duplicates of each other.  How can I use except to solve that problem?

Comment: -- oh, I see -- it looked like I was calling the java compareTo method.  I renamed the method to computeSimilarity to clarify that I'm not looking for exact equality here.

Comment: just try broadcast